# finding if substring exists in file in python

Tags: python, search, substring

I have 2 files. One is my "keyfile" and other is "lookupfile". I'am trying to check if line in keyfile is present in lookup.Here's my code snippet

```
lookupfile = open("riskeng_recon_e_mso_transact_db_msoinputapplication_t2.txt","r")

with open("1.txt","r") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        print "-------------checking for "+line+"-----------"
        for x in lookupfile:
            #print x
            if str(line) in str(x):
                print "Line present"+line
```

My 2 files have records in this format.

```
Lookupfile:

1234asfd
32453sdfvs
sfgagss234

keyfile:

123
3245
124
```

My issue here is that after taking first record from key file and comparing it with lookupfile, it is not moving forward with the next record in lookupfile.

Comment: `open` returns an iterator, so I don't think that nested for-loop is going to run more than once. use `lookupfile = lookupfile.readlines()` or `lookupfile = list(lookupfile)`

Comment: Do you want to do pair-wise comparison, line 1 from one file with line 1 from the other file and so on?

Comment: @schwobaseggl No. I need to compare key with complete lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it now, you exhaust the lookup iterator in the first outer loop iteration. The time complexity of the nested loops is `O(M*N*L)` where `L` is the average length of the lookup lines which for two long files can be too much. You can create a sorted suffix array of your lookup strings and use binary search for each key:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

with open("1.txt") as myfile, open('...') as lookup:
    # sorted lookup suffix array
    l_u = sorted(l[i:] for l in lookup for i in range(1, len(l)))
    for line in myfile:
        if l_u[bisect_left(l_u, line)].startswith(line):
            print('Line "{}" exists'.format(line))
```

The time complexity is now `O(N*L*log(N*L) + M*log(N*L))`. For large files with relatively short lines (such that `L*log(N*L)` and `log(N*L)` are much smaller than `M,N`) this should be significantly better than `O(M*N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can do the operation while reading too:
Since pair-wise wasn't what you wanted we need to create a list with the rows from lookupfile to reuse it.

```
with open("file1.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""\
1234asfd
32453sdfvs
sfgagss234""")

with open("file2.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""\
123
3245
124
324""")


with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    # Store lookupfile in list  
    lookup = f1.read().split("\n")

    # Loop lookupfile for every line in keyfile
    for idx, line in enumerate(f2,1):
        for idy, row in enumerate(lookup,1):
            # Look for match
            if line.strip() in row:
                print("line {} present on line {}".format(idx,idy))
```

Prints

```
line 1 present on line 1
line 2 present on line 2
line 4 present on line 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Create two lists `listkf` and `listlookup` by reading the files

```
listkf=[]
with open("keyfile", 'r') as kf:
    for line in kf:
        listkf.append(line.strip())    # adding key to list after stripping 

listlookup=[]
with open("Lookupfile", 'r') as lf:
    for line in lf:
        listlookup.append(line)
```

Assuming you need line by line match

```
for i in range(len(listlookup)):
    if listkf[i] in listlookup[i]:
         print("key exists")
    else:
         print("key does not exist")
```

If `key` in `keyfile` is to be looked up in entire `Lookupfile`

```
for x in listkf:
    for y in listlookup:
        if x in str(y):
            print("key ", x, " exists")
            break
```

Comment: +1 for using list.But, Wouldn't it increase the time complexity in insertion if I have large number of records in key and lookup.

Comment: This does only pairwise comparison, not cross wise each line in file 1 with each line in file 2